# Access violation on program termination C++

Tags: c++

I'm new at this. This is a project for school using Borland 5.02.

It seems that whenever I terminate the program I get an "access violation" error; I need help please.

Our teacher told us to make use of `iostream.h` and `conio.h`

This is the entire code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

int exit=1;

main()
{
  do
  {
    exit=1;
    cin>>exit;
  }while(exit!=0);
  return(0);
  getche();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. At least you should properly format the code, and reduce it to the minimum required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you using a very old compiler? And why are you calling getche() after you return 0?

Comment: Please Format your code so that inner blocks are more indented than outer blocks (for all Loops, for each if). Right now your code is not readable, it is hard to see the flow of control.

Comment: hahaha gee thanks @JonathanLeffler that helped  lol

sorry for the disturbance XD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rename your variable `exit` to a name that does not conflict with a standard library function.  The program is probably jumping to the code contained in your variable (hint: there isn't any) instead of being able to jump the system library function `exit()`.

Note that the `<iostream.h>` header is from pre-standard C++ and it really isn't something that you should be using in modern C++ (if your compiler was from the current millennium rather than the last).  Also, no C++ compiler should accept `main()` with no return type; you should have written `int main()`.  If Borland 5.02 does accept that code, you seriously need to upgrade to a standard compiler — preferably a C++11 compiler rather than a C++98 or C++03 compiler.  Note that C++11 is a rather different language from C++98, and C++98 is a radically different language from pre-standard C++.  You are being given a seriously sub-standard education if you are being forced to use a pre-standard C++ compiler.